# How do you handle incomplete data in a Processing table?

Tags: java, processing

I'm parsing a CSV using Processing's `Table` interface, but some rows are missing some data. I want to pull all the data available into my table, but I'm not sure how to handle the missing data--I keep getting `NullPointerException` when I loop over the table with `dataTable.getInt` on the missing values.

I don't have a background in statically typed languages, so I've no idea how to conditionally assign this data short of putting a separate `try`/`catch` around each assignment. Surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out a way to do this:

First, call `dataTable.makeNullEmpty()`, which turns all the null values into empty strings.

Then, you can use a pattern like this:

```
String total_value = dataTable.getString(i, 4);
if(total_value.length() > 0) s.total_value = parseInt(total_value);
```

and you get assignment only if an int is there to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling dataTable.getInt method check if dataTable is not null like

```
if(dataTable != null) {
    int my_nt = dataTable.getInt

}
//else skip since it is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your're using getInt--you should perform a `regex search/replace ,<not numeric>, with ,<some int>,`.  In your case it may be as simple as replacing ,, with ,0,

Also, as Hassan suggests, double check that dataTable is not null.